# Where to find qgsaffine in the menu?

Tags: qgis

I installed the plugin qgsaffine but cannot find the entry in the menu bar. Where do I find this. Can anyone here help me with this?

Answer (score 8):

In Qgis, Select Plugins > Manage Plugins and Select the qgsaffine plugin.

In Menu, it is located at Plugins > Geoprocessing > Affine

[image]

Comment: It looks like qgsaffine isn't available for qgis 2.x any more. Is this correct and if yes, is there a replacement?

Comment: @boundaryfunctions - it is probably not yet updated to 2.0..many plugins are still catching up to the latest version..

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ok, I suppose you're right, so let's just wait for the update.

Answer (score 2):

in normal installing qgis plugins locate under Plugins menu. i think you have to re-install it again because of wrong installaion or bugs...

you can also look at your plugin folder under `Quantum GIS ... > apps > qgis > plugins` or `Quantum GIS ... > apps > qgis > python > plugins` whether qgsaffine is there or not...

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

You can find it now under **Vector** (version 2.6.1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think they renamed it. Got to Plugins->Fetch Python Plugins... and select "Affine Transformations". You won't find it under qgsaffine anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For *Geoprocessing* of **DEM** in **QGIS 2.0** , there is an alternative to use **qgSurf** plugin. Hereby the description from the **qgSurf** developer:

> This plugin allows to calculate the best-fit plane give a DEM and a set of points, or alternatively, given a geological plane, a DEM and a point, to calculate the intersections of the plane with the DEM.

I want to point out on the difference and similarity of those two plugin.
`qgsaffine` plugin concerns on doing affine transformation, which is translation, rotation, scale on a vector. This function is basically covered in `qgsurf` plugin.

`qqsaffine` is developed in github and the `qgsurf` is bitbucket but both are python based developed plugin.

I wish that I can improve this answer more. Feel free to give some more constructive information to be added. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. This answer would be better you explain the differences / commonality between qgSurf and qgsaffine, and why one would choose one over the other. You don't need to bold nouns either.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3x you can find it in the toolbox:

Toolbox - Vector Geometry - Affine transformation.

Just start type Affine in the Toolbox search, you will get it on the list shortly.

[image]

Comment: This was added in Qgis 3.12 to be exact https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/#feature-add-native-affine-transform-algorithm-for-vectors