# Illustrator to QGIS workflow for vectors

Tags: qgis, vector, georeferencing

I vectorized a map in Illustrator and would like to import it to QGIS now. I know I must use DXF for that purpose but when I convert the DXF to SHP with the QGIS plugin it is not georeferenced which is actually not surprising. But the QGIS georeferencing tool works for raster images only. So what to do?

The base TIFF image I used as the bottom layer in Illu is georeferenced, so maybe I can use the settings from there but I didn't figure out how. I heard you can use the .prj file from another layer but my TIFF doesn't have this, it has a .points only.

Answer (score 2):

The better workflow is to:

1. Georeference the raster in QGIS
2. Digitize/Vectorize in QGIS

Depending on your map, the above workflow will still be faster than attempting to georeference the vectors you created, compare: [How to georeference a vector layer with control points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that QGIS is unable to georeference a vector layer and you have to switch to another program like Openjump or ArcGIS. The Affine Transformations plugin is not a solution because you have to provide the parameters yourselves. This is really a basic functionality missing!

Comment: @tanGIS Everyone's pet function is a "basic functionality" ;)