# Relocating & resizing complex shapefile with OpenSource Software

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dem

(please excuse my poor english)

I do have a polygone shapefile of an archaelogical site with elevation data of 10cm steps and I dont get hands on the raster data as it was collected by the drone.

My problem is, that I need to move and resize the polygones, due to even though the shape say's it is a DHDN/GK3, the lower-left corner of the collected data is 0,0 and the x & y extends seam to be decimenter relative to this origin.

Is there any useful way to solve the problem with QGIS + tools (using Ubuntu Linux) ?

My so far best thought is....

a) CSV-Geometry export via MMQGIS (temp-nodes.csv, temp-attributes.csv)
   The CSV counts ~8.500.000 nodes
b) Suggest origin from so far data (kept as variable)
c) pipe node-csv through script to convert decimeter to meter,
   to get the new delta x/y from the origin
d) add the new delta x/y to the origin and save
e) CSV-Geometry improt via MMQGIS

Is there any way to solve this easier?
It's been years since I have written scripts.

Chris

Comment: This question might give you further hints: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-for-archaeological-site-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Since version 1.10, you can use ogr2ogr (GDAL) to agjust/"georeference" a shapefile with control points or GCPs (as [Spatial adjustment](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000t5000000) in ArcGIS, look at [How to georeference a vector layer with control points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points) or [Add ability to transform vectors based on GCPs in ogr2ogr](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4604))

Example

```
ogr2ogr -gcp 5 -135 0 0 \
     -gcp 283 -135 1000 0 \
     -gcp 5 278 0 1000 \
     -gcp 283 278 1000 1000 \
     -f "ESRI shapefile" gcppolyg2.shp gcppolyg.shp
```

Simple result with scaling, translation, rotation and shearing of a simple original shapefile

[image]

Two QGIS plugins and a processing python script were created to take advantage of this feature:

Plugins:

1. [VectorBender](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/): does to vectors what georeferencers does to raster. This feature is also known as "rubber sheeting"
2. [vectorgeoref](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vectGeoref/) : a visual tool to georeferencing vector layers

Processing Python script (in French):

- [QGIS 2 - script and method to georeference vectors](http://www.portailsig.org/content/qgis-2-script-et-methode-pour-faire-du-georeferencement-vectoriel)

2) You can also use affine transformations with the QGIS plugin [Affine](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAffine/) or the command [v.transform](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.transform.html) in GRASS GIS or in the Processing Toolbox of QGIS

[image]

There are equivalent commands in [GVSIG](http://foss4gis.blogspot.be/2011/05/computing-and-applying-affine.html) or [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/)

[image]

Affine transformation in [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/)