# How to coincide two geometries which has difference in positioning?

Tags: qgis

I have two vector layers one representing countries and other representing states. I have states which is slightly dis positioned so that it is not exactly not coinciding with the country.Algorithm help is required .How can it be done in QGIS.Please find the image below for better explanation.The yellow should coincide with the outer linestring of green.
[image]
[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: The entire green features should exactly coincide on the yellow feature of the red vector layer .How this can be done moving using edit tool disturbs green features

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to transform your states layer again. Please see the link:
[How to georeference a vector layer with control points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points)

Answer (score 0):

If the yellow line is one complete polygon, in edit mode you could move them manually,select the features(yellow polygon) then select the move tool and shift them.

Comment: Have you made sure its not an issue of different projections causing the small shift?