# Projecting SHP file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, autocad, dxf

I have a DXF file of a building from AutoCAD. I saved this DXF file as a SHP file in QGIS. But this SHP file is converted from a plain DXF file and is not referenced/projected, it is drawn from coordinates 0,0 in AutoCAD in meters.
And the drawing has meters, WGS84 has decimal degrees.

When I set Layer CRS as WGS84 in QGIS, the coordinates don't change.

How can I project this SHP file as WGS84 in QGIS?

Comment: Please update your previous question to add further details.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to geo-reference the data in the DXF. If it has been drawn at 0,0 it is not in real world co-ordinates so trying to re-project will do nothing.

If you know where the data should be in UTM (or some other projection) you can move it in AutoCAD to the correct location, then re-save and import back into QGIS. Then you will be able to convert to WGS84 and export as a shapefile.

Comment: Is there a way to do this just in QGIS? 1) How can i convert units from meters to decimal degrees for this SHP polygon? 2) How can i move to the correct location?

Comment: Don't worry about the units. They will sort themselves out once you are in WGS84. You just need to sort the geo-referencing of your DXF data. You can do this in QGIS or AutoCAD, but either way you will need a point of reference. So you will need to find the co-ordinates of your building, in order to move the DXF data to the right location. Another question on geo-referencing using QGIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points