# Projecting a dxf on QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dxf, cad

I need to use a waste dump .dxf on a map but unfortunately I'm not able to match the projection with the others I have. I'm working with Google hybrid using CRS: EPSG:32632 WGS84 / UTM zone 32N and this is the area I'm working on:

[image]

And I'm trying to use this .dxf which is projected far away from the ara of interest:

[image]

I think there's something wrong with the projection I'm using, but even changing the CRS of the layer doesn't change the result.

Here's the dxf: https://infinit.io/_/3cygVkS

Comment: Did you reproject the satellite picture to EPSG:32632?

Comment: Yes I did. But the .dxf is still projected near Africa instead in Italy as expected :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, you may find this custom CRS to fit rather good:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +x_0=-100022 +y_0=-4901952 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

This makes me think the projection is Monte Mario Zone 1, with the leading digits cut off:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=-100000 +y_0=-4900000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Thank you @AndreJ! the custom CRS you passed me works perfect!

Answer (score 3):

The middle of your DXF are approximately x: 24,500 y: 20,500.
Your Google Picture is located at approximately EPSG: 32632 X: (32) 625,000 Y: 4,920,500.
It looks like you have to move your DXF by x: 600,000 y: 4900.000.

I have tested again:
Create a CRS for the DXF with the following values:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=-100000 +y_0=-4900000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: You can georeference data in QGIS/ogr2ogr but it is not too straightforward: http://gisforthought.com/georeferencing-vector-data-using-qgis-and-ogr2ogr/

Comment: @Mike What's the best way to move the DXF to the right position?

Comment: V1) use a extern tool for DXF(Unknown to me)   
V2) Convert the DXF to Shape (PlugIn Another DXF Shape Converter)  
Move the  Shape(s) with QGIS (PlugIn Affine Transformations)

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that all your projection settings are right and it still does not work, you might want to try vector georeferencing aka "rubber sheeting". See [How to georeference a vector layer with control points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points) and/or try the [VectorBender](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/) plugin.