# Georeferencing a traced polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, georeferencing

As a novice, I have drawn a DXF polygon (traced from a UK Ordnance /survey map of unknown scale).
It has no geographic reference and when I import it to QGIS (with a Google Maps base layer) and save as a shapefile it places it near the equator. I have tried to 'move' it up to the UK but that distorts the polygon proportions. I guess I need to do something a little more sophisticated to move it to the UK with its scale and proportions etc to fit over the Google map. Any pointers?

Comment: What map projection did you choose for your layer when exporting it to .shp format?

Comment: The problem you are having is maybe related to the CRS (Coordinate Reference System) settings. When loading the DXF in QGIS it is necessary to assign a CRS according to the original CRS captured vectors. From the menu Layer -> Layer Properties -> Source you can access to this settings

Comment: Another option (if there is no geographic information at all included in the file) is to georeference the file - in newer QGIS version, that's possible for vector layers as well - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438798/88814