# Converting from unknown coordinate system into common one using fiducial points?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a thousand of points that I want to project in a different coordinate system. These points were generated using an old and odd coordinate system (let's call it CS) so it's not possible to use some library to convert them. Luckily for each 50 points I have 1 point in both coordinate systems (the old and odd CS system and the WGS84). So how can I convert the remaining 49 points to WGS84. I think it is matter of interpolation but I don't know the math to use.

[image]

I have the WGS84 and the CS coordinates of the *red* points,
I need the WGS84 coordinates of the *black* points.

I know how to do this in QGIS using a custom CRS string with 1 point but here I need at least 3 points because 1 point will only move the layer. I also need to scale or deform.

Is it possible to have a custom CRS string based on 3 points?

I am also interested by the math to use (I will eventually do the math in Python).

Comment: You can create a custom coordinate system for most Projection engines. What software do you prefer?

Comment: I'm starting with QGIS, is there some plugin?

Comment: Take 3 known points at the 'corners', calculate affine transformation parameters and recalculate all geometries

Comment: Here is the qgis plugin explained, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25193/where-to-find-qgsaffine-in-the-menu

Comment: GIS libraries can reproject almost every "old and odd" coordinate system. Mercator invented his system in 1569, surely older than your data. You just have to calculate the parameters. With a few points in both systems, it is easy to calculate the origin of the projection, and define a custom projection on it.

Comment: As Andre says: 'GIS libraries can reproject almost every "old and odd" coordinate system'.  Does QGIS recognise the projection?  If so, just do 'Save As' and define the new projection for the ouptut in the dialog box.

Comment: – AndreJ I know with a few points in both systems I can calculate the origin but the question is how, do you have some tutorial?

Comment: If you can share a sample of points in both CRS (3 at least), I can write one ;-)